# How to get the link to be clickable below because of blocked table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to place the text infront of the table as shown in the picture below? For one of my responsive query, the link appears behind the table and the only way that I know how to fix this is to move the table away from the drop down menu but is there a way that I can put the drop down menu link in front[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOmpl.png) of the table to make it clickable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Plase add your attempts to the question.

Comment: While Smollet777 and DaFois are so awesome that they are helping you to get started with StackOverflow, I will just give you a hit that might help you with your problem: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: I have heard about that... but thought I did try it... will try it again... thanks!

Comment: I already have the following z-index in my code but not really sure how it works

Comment: label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;

}

Comment: that is for my drop down menu

Comment: I got it to work by using z index and making sure I am using positioning or it won't work.. thanks!